# Style dynamic content for printing

Tags: javascript, css, printing-web-page

I have an app which at one point creates some contracts.

The problem is that **my content is very dynamic**, and the contract is really official so the formatting maters a lot,.

Furthermore **i also have footnotes**, which are again dynamic depending on the content.

Here is an example:
[image]

This image is all ready formatted in word.

So right now I'm using a jQuery plugin named **[Columnizer](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/)** but its still not ok, if i give fix height for my content, then either the footnotes will fail or the content will brake when it shouldn't.

Any idea how i could make it somehow dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try converting your Word document to another format such as HTML (word2cleanhtml.com or something) and then format the HTML the way you want (or convert to pdf using wkhtmltopdf or princexml).